# Resizing images on TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    // Set the data for this cell:

        cell.textLabel.text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:14];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
        cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;

        [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55)];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

       return cell;
}
```

Here I'm using just `TableView` not `UITableViewCell`, but I want to resize images on `TableView`. I've taken a look at many examples on the internet, however I don't understand how any of them work - I'm not able to get them resized on `TableView`. Could someone explain how to get it working?  [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55)]; is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i put logic of both Crop and resize image, use it as per your requirement.

**For Get Cropped Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(AS YOu Need); // set frame as you need
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

The following method that return `UIImage` (*as You want size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Here you get Croped Image that return by above method;

**OR RESIZING**

And also use following method with specific **hight** and **width** of image for Resizing:

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(CGFloat)width withHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    CGFloat widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    CGFloat heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the aspect of the cell (for example the size of the image view) you need to use a custom `UITableViewCell`. Currently you are using a standard cell `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` which doesn't let you customize the size of the image view.

Create an `UITableViewCell` in storyboard or in a Xib file, add it your image view and set its tag to a number. After that you need to retrieve the cell for configuring it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:TAG_NUMBER];
    // do your stuff

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this. Just add a new imageView under the cell's contentView atleast it will be easier for you to set the frame.

And just to clarify you are already using UITableviewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// Create a new imageview to have your desired frame

  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)];

 // Add tag 
  imgView.tag = 100;

// Add the imageView to the contentView of the cell
 [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

}

// Other codes


UIImageView *imageV = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
// Assign Image here
imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

   return cell;
}
```